# Debug error when debugging OpenGL program remotely

Tags: linux, opengl

I can use gdb to debug my OpenGL program on the server locally. But when I Debug it  remotely. some errors come out in  `glutCreateWindow()` function. And I can run my program remotely. Just can't debug .

```
freeglut (/home/fshen/samuel/project_self/GLSL-learning/teapotshader/teapotshader): 
     ERROR:  Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities not found> in 
             function fgOpenWindow
        X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
          Major opcode of failed request:  4 (X_DestroyWindow)
          Resource id in failed request:  0x0
          Serial number of failed request:  20
          Current serial number in output stream:  23
```

**PS:**
 First I can't run my program remotely. After setting `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=yes` (I put this command in .bash_profile),I can run my project. Just can't debug it remotely. So I think i should  add `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=yes` into the GDB. But I don't know howto do it?

Comment: @genpfault: Sorry for the mistake. openGL

Comment: What happens if you do `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=yes` in a terminal and then run `gdb` from that terminal?

Comment: @n.m: The error which I mentioned comes out

Comment: Well, you can try `set env LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=yes` from inside `gdb` before running the program. But I'm not sure whether it would work differently from just doing the export in the terminal, or indeed putting it in `.bash_profile`.